# Rails 3.2 refactoring views: how to choose paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.2 and haml

I have a many code like this in my views:

```
= link_to obj.get_title, @client ? agency_obj_path(@client.id, obj.get_id) : obj_path(obj.get_id)
...
= link_to t('aa.actions.edit_mini'), @client ? edit_agency_obj_path(@client.id, obj.get_id) : edit_obj_path(obj.get_id), class: 'action', title: t('aa.action_titles.objects.edit')
```

And I want to refactor `@client ? agency_obj_path(@client.id, obj.get_id) : obj_path(obj.get_id)`. May be use some helper?

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to t('aa.actions.edit_mini'),edit_path(obj), 
  class: 'action', title: t('aa.action_titles.objects.edit')
```

Now define your edit_path helper method in your **applicaiton_helper.rb** or **"agency_helper.rb"(if you have)**

**Note:** you don't need to pass instance variable(@client), it's available there in helper.

```
#application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def edit_path(obj) 
    return edit_obj_path(obj.get_id) if @client.blank?
    edit_agency_obj_path(@client.id, obj.get_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: It's good, but I have many different paths (index, edit, show etc..) How to create universal helper for all of this?

Comment: You can put those helpers methods in ApplicationHelper, this will be accessible every where. :)